# Excel VBA User form navigation conundrum

Tags: navigation, runtime-error, userform, keyboard-events, setfocus

This was asked about 3 years+ ago and no solution that works was given:

[Set focus on UserForm Textbox on tabbing from another Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440050/set-focus-on-userform-textbox-on-tabbing-from-another-textbox)

I have a user form and want the navigation to the next text box to happen automatically after the correct data entry has been entered (so for example if i know that the correct number of characters for the text box is 2 then after two characters have been entered it automatically moves to the next text box).

My issue is with error checking, what (for example) if someone is entering their day of birth in the first of 3 fields for their date of birth, and they enter 32. Then I want a message box telling them to enter 2 digits between 1 and 31, empty the field and give it back the focus, so effectively halting the process until they enter the right data.

Second possible scenario is that they enter 0 then try to tab to the next text box. I would then want the same thing.

Problem is that it will not do this.

Setfocus is superceded by the next field in the tab order which automatically gets the focus no matter what I try (and I tried lots of things including all the solutions given in the earlier post).

Anyone got any ideas how this might be worked around?

Kind regards, Mark

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim inputVal As String
inputVal = TextBox1.Value
    If Len(inputVal) = 2 Then
        If IsNumeric(inputVal) Then
            If inputVal <= 31 And CInt(inputVal) = CDbl(inputVal) Then
                TextBox2.SetFocus
            Else
                MsgBox ("Must be <=31 and integer")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox ("Must be a number")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Generally you can use the _change() to control what's going on, so you can do say "if tb1.value = 0 then "... or you can use the similar logic to restrict values to be a certain length (no more than 2 chars) or control that they're numbers etc etc.

Comment: Thanks Viktor, of course Change is a much better place then Exit to error check and solves my issue, (rookie mistake I guess). It solves my issue, except if the user back spaces twice to delete the cell content or if I pro grammatically set the content to "". The control then appears to retain focus but the cursor is not on the control so the user then has to click it to re renter, is there any workaround to have the cursor show up in the control in question even if I set its contents to"" to have them try again?

Comment: @MarkStephens -- not sure what the issue is. If the contents of tbox1 is literally "" (two double quotes) that is 2 chars not a number so that triggers the warning. If you mean two spaces that's the same. If they backtrack 2x to have a blank value that's a somewhat different thing but you can always do if len(xxx) = 0 then msgbox 'something'

Comment: Thanks Viktor, we can discuss when we meet tomorrow, would you be able to come to Uxbridge in the afternoon?